# How do I append a value to an array in a JavaScript object while mapping through the object its contained in?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript object of the following structure:

```
results = [
   {
      date: ... // holds a string representing a date
      timeslots: [
         {
           slotsAvailable: ... // holds an int
           time: ... // holds a string representing time
         },
         {
           slotsAvailable: ...
           time: ... 
         }
      ] 
   },
   {
      date: ... 
      timeslots: [
         {
           slotsAvailable: ... 
           time: ... 
         },
         {
           slotsAvailable: ...
           time: ... 
         }
      ] 
   },
   {
      date: ... 
      timeslots: [
         {
           slotsAvailable: ... 
           time: ... 
         },
         {
           slotsAvailable: ...
           time: ... 
         }
      ] 
   }
]
```

The object starts off empty and I fill it through the following code:

```
    "timeslots": [
        {
            "slotsAvailable": 1,
            "time": "2022-02-11T14:00:00-0500"
        },
        {
            "slotsAvailable": 1,
            "time": "2022-02-13T13:40:00-0500"
        },
        {
            "slotsAvailable": 1,
            "time": "2022-02-15T17:40:00-0500"
        },
        {
            "slotsAvailable": 1,
            "time": "2022-02-15T18:20:00-0500"
        },
        {
            "slotsAvailable": 1,
            "time": "2022-02-16T14:00:00-0500"
        },
        {
            "slotsAvailable": 1,
            "time": "2022-02-16T14:20:00-0500"
        },
        {
            "slotsAvailable": 1,
            "time": "2022-02-17T21:40:00-0500"
        }
    ]

    var results = []
    
    let date = new Date(timeslots[0].time)
    for(let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        results = [...results, {date: new Date(date), timeslots: []}] // Date function called b/c otherwise value is passed by reference
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
    } 

    console.log(results)

    for(const i in timeslots) {
        let slot = timeslots[i]

        results.map(result => {
            return result.date.getDate() === new Date(slot.time).getDate() 
                   ? {...result, timeslots: [...result.timeslots, slot]} // this line doesn't work
                   : result
        })
    }

    console.log(results)
```

The `results` object correctly populates with 8 dates in the first loop, but after the second loop, all of the `timeslots` arrays are still empty. The intended result is that the final object contains an array of dates where each timeslot is placed in the object corresponding to its date.

I believe the error is with the line in the second loop where I spread in the existing array and append a new value to the array, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Is this how you expect your output to be?

```js
const timeslots= [{"slotsAvailable": 1,"time": "2022-02-11T14:00:00-0500"},{"slotsAvailable": 1,"time": "2022-02-13T13:40:00-0500"},{"slotsAvailable": 1,"time": "2022-02-15T17:40:00-0500"},{"slotsAvailable": 1,"time": "2022-02-15T18:20:00-0500"},{"slotsAvailable": 1,"time": "2022-02-16T14:00:00-0500"},{"slotsAvailable": 1,"time": "2022-02-16T14:20:00-0500"},{"slotsAvailable": 1,"time": "2022-02-17T21:40:00-0500"}]

const results = timeslots.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const date = curr.time.split('T')[0];
  const time = curr.time.split('T')[1];
  const dateTime = date + ' ' + time;
  const dateTimeObject = new Date(dateTime);
  const dateString = dateTimeObject.toDateString();
  const timeString = dateTimeObject.toLocaleTimeString();
  const timeObject = {
    slotsAvailable: curr.slotsAvailable,
    time: timeString,
  };
  if (acc.length === 0) {
    acc.push({
      date: dateString,
      timeslots: [timeObject],
    });
  } else {
    const lastIndex = acc.length - 1;
    const lastDate = acc[lastIndex].date;
    if (lastDate === dateString) {
      acc[lastIndex].timeslots.push(timeObject);
    } else {
      acc.push({
        date: dateString,
        timeslots: [timeObject],
      });
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%  !important; top:0px}
```